# Automapper with Record types causing StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, automapper, stack-overflow

Mapping from Entity type to DTO type using **AutoMapper** causes StackOverflow exception due to referential loops when I'm using records for DTOs. However, when I use classes for DTOs I still have an infinite nesting, but it's not throwing a StackOverflowException and this can be fixed by configuring JSON to ignore *Referential Loops*.

I tried to configure mapping with **MaxDepth**, **PreserveReferences()**, Ignoring properties like this:

```
CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Products, r => r.Ignore());
```

none of these approaches worked, I found similar questions on **SO** and issues on **GitHub**, but still can't figure out the reason of why it's happening and how to fix it properly.

**Entities**

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**DTOs**

```
public record ProductDto(
    int Id,
    string Name,
    decimal Price
    CategoryDto Category);

public record CategoryDto(
    int Id,
    string Name,
    string? Description
    ICollection<ProductDto> Products);
```

**Mappings**

```
public class ProductMappings : Profile
{
    public ProductMappings()
    {
        CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
            .PreserveReferences();
    }
}

public class CategoryMappings : Profile
{
    public CategoryMappings()
    {
        CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>()
            .PreserveReferences();
    }
}
```

**EF Core query logic**

```
public async Task<PaginatedList<Category>> FindAllAsync(CategoryQueryParameters queryParameters)
{
    var query = _context.Categories.AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryParameters.SearchQuery))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(queryParameters.SearchQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

    var entities = await query
        .Include(x => x.Products)
        .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()
        .ToPaginatedListAsync(queryParameters.PageNumber, queryParameters.PageSize);

    return entities;
}
```

**Service logic where mapping happens**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CategoryDto>> GetAsync(CategoryQueryParameters queryParameters)
{
    var paginatedResult = await _repository.ProductCategory.FindAllAsync(queryParameters);

    return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoryDto>>(paginatedResult);
}
```

Here is the log from database call:
[image]

I understand that it can be fixed by changing the design and removing nested references in DTOs, but I'm curios about the reason of why it's happening. Initially I thought that AutoMapper is unable to handle in record types loop references due to record types being compared by value, and not reference, but this does not appear to be the case.

Comment: Do you use `AsNoTracking`? If YES, try `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution`. And turn on `PreserveReferences`

Comment: Yes, I was using `AsNoTracking`. Using `AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution` with `PreserveReferences` didn't work neither.

Comment: Can you show your LINQ query?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I have added more context.

Comment: Try creating the destination objects without AM.

Comment: Check this [Circular references](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#circular-references) - *If you’re still getting `StackOverflowException`, open an issue with a full repro and we’ll look into it.*

Comment: That's not the case here. I don't see how you can possibly create the destination objects.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Can you elaborate on what you mean? As I wrote in the description the destination objects are created without any issues if I use **classes** for DTOs, so I don't get why you're saying it's not possible to create destination objects.

Comment: Show me the code in C# to create those as records, not as classes.

Comment: Do you mean the DTOs? Entities use POCO classes, DTOs use Records types as shown in the code above. From repository I fetch entities, then in **Service** those entities are mapped into DTOs which are record types. The above example shows the usage of records, if I replace DTO types from records to a class type then there is no `StackOverflowException` even though there is an infinite reference loop. If I remove the nested objects (References from one type to another) mapping also succeeds without issues, but this is not what I need.

Comment: Of course the DTOs, that's what you want AM to instantiate.

Comment: I don't create them manually, I only map from **Entity** types to **DTO** types using AM. I'm not sure which code do you want to see exactly. ``_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoryDto>>(paginatedResult);`` Here where the mapping happens from **Entity** types to **DTO** types. In the service example I receive a list of **Entities** which I then map to a list of **DTOs**.